# JAVA SESSION Cookie issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, session, cookies

I want my web application to resume its session when the browser is restarted. So I had use the following code in cookie Filter to create SESSION cookie for any request other than login and logout.

```
HttpSession browserSession = httpRequest.getSession();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("SESSION", browserSession.getId());
cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);     
httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

If I login to my appl and restart the browser and access url, it's getting login automatically (as expected). But if I logout in that session and then try to login in that session, it's not getting logged in. What's causing this issue?

when i fetch cookies from request(httpRequest.getCookies()), i get 2 cookies with SESSION name , one is browser created and one is which my code created but while debuging both are having the same max age i.e -1 when i set my cookie max age as Integer.MaxValue()?? why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

You can try **deleting the coockie when logged out**, this way user will be identified by the coockie created while logging in and will be  valid for a session (from login to logout) and as soonest as user logs out  earlier coockie will be deleted.

Comment: I tried deleting the cookie during logout, but for the scenario where user is logged in and closes the browser and then opens after some time then user is logged in automatically, if user logs out and then try to log in, its not getting logged in.

Comment: String requestPath = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
         if(requestPath.contains("logout")){
           cookie.setValue(null);
           cookie.setMaxAge(0);
           httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
}